# What is the best way to handle common files for DotNetNuke modules and skins?

Tags: tfs, dotnetnuke

We are currently moving over a large website to DotNetNuke (version 7.2.1). We're creating separate projects for each module and skin, source controlled in TFS. We were not planning on adding the actual DNN source code itself to TFS. I would like to be able to access common files, such as JS and CSS, among different solution/projects. Is there a recommended way to do this without source controlling the DNN source code project itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create local Nuget packages? :D That might be overkill for such a scenario.

You could always create a single project/module, that all the other modules reference the path for the original resources, so that they all point to the same location.

Comment: If I created a new project, would you recommend building its files to one of the DNN source folders?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add any DNN related source in TFS, it means that you have to setup a identical structure on the disk and in IIS. Then in your ascx/css files you can use URIs that are either relative to your disk structure or your dev website.

If you create a specific project for the resources, you will put parts of the DNN codebase in your TFS. If it is not a showstopper for you, consider adding the elements to the solution instead, since there is no logical partitioning of these resources as a project. I would however recommend using URIs.

As a side note, please refer to the [Client Resource Management API](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/client-resource-management-api) of DNN for your future devs in order to benefit from the minification and combination of resources.

Comment: Thank you. Why would you recommend using the URIs rather than source control a few resource folders? Thanks, just trying to figure out the best solution for us!

Comment: I was offering a solution to the fact that you were not planning to add the DNN source code to TFS. What's more, URIs let you catch potential problems such as using the ~ path root, which resolves to different places when using an app or a virtual directory under IIS. If you want to add the resources to TFS, go ahead, though